# Continuous delivery with capistrano/chef/puppet: where do you store your artifacts?

Tags: capistrano, chef-infra, puppet

I've been reading up on how people do continuous delivery with some of the popular toolsets.

Lots of posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137424/how-can-puppet-fit-into-a-continuous-delivery-tool-chain?rq=1) one) seem to indicate that a common way of doing things is to use something like capistrano to push software from your builds to your machines, and then chef or puppet to configure anything related to it.

My question is, do people generally push there software directly into a special git repo for binary assets, or can capistrano fetch it out of a maven repo? The maven approach seems most natural to me, but I don't seem to be able to find much information on it - which is what makes me think it's not the approach that people are generally taking.

Basically, I'm slightly confused as there seems to be a gap between the build output (where one would normally publish to a maven repo) - and where the delivery tools expect to find the software you have asked them to deploy (which seems to be a file system, or a git repo)

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to artifacts; I attempt to leverage the jenkins plugin to upload to S3. Here's a [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/S3+Plugin) to it.

Basiclly right now, all my ci goes through Jenkins and when I get a complete build I upload it to a bucket and have chef pull the tarball/war/gem from it and install it from there.

Comment: cool - thanks - do you ALSO publish to maven for versioning as well, or is S3 the only place you store your artifacts?

Comment: I only store in S3. Makes life easier.